# Не сохранить документ xsl

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте, есть сетка, в ней есть счета для манагеров, они обычно сразу сохраняют файлы на сервер. но сейчас у одного случилась проблема, при сохранении пишет:Предупреждение при сохранении документа Ошибка записи.Все изменения кода Basic утеряны. Вместо этого будет сохранен макрокод VBA

Не подскажете что нужно сделать? я уже и обновил до новой версии libre и openoffice ставил, нифига... Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1):

Если это только у одного человека из всей системы документооборота, то это наводит на мысль, что либо один этот юзер попробовал юзать MS Office 2013, либо у него в документе какая-то дрянь сидит!